# discord.js trying to DM random person gif

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I recently started making my own discord bot and I am trying to DM a random person from server gif. Problem is when i write command it only chooses me or bot. Same for my friends. I tried many things but everything I tried didnt work so that is why i am asking here.
Here is my code:

```
module.exports = {
    name:'gif',
    description: 'sending random person gif in DM',
    execute(message, args){
        const list = message.guild.members.cache.array();
        const users = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
        const dm = list[users];
        if(dm.user.id === '820258978390474773') return;
        dm.send('https://tenor.com/view/funny-animals-dog-dance-cute-smile-gif-12759384');
        console.log(`${dm}`);
        message.channel.send(`${dm} got the gif`);
    }
}
```

and this is code in my main javascript file

```
if(message.channel.id === '820260807010156574' && command === 'gif'){
        client.commands.get('gif').execute(message, args);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Discord API, but what is the content of the `list` array? I wonder if `message.guild.members.cache.array()` is not returning what you expect.

Comment: List array basically collects user id of every user on server and converts it to array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that might be because your friend isn't in the guild's member cache. You can fetch members in the guild before executing `message.guild.members.cache.array()` using `message.guild.members.fetch()`.

```js
module.exports = {
    name:'gif',
    description: 'sending random person gif in DM',
    async execute(message, args){
        await message.guild.members.fetch();
        const list = message.guild.members.cache.array();
        const users = Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
        const dm = list[users];
        if(dm.user.id === '820258978390474773') return;
        dm.send('https://tenor.com/view/funny-animals-dog-dance-cute-smile-gif-12759384');
        console.log(`${dm}`);
        message.channel.send(`${dm} got the gif`);
    }
}
```

I added async & await, so the code is executed after discord.js fetches for new guild members

Comment: This is working thanks for help I really appreciate